# Query aggregate match with filters specified in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Henrik",
  "info" : {
      "phone" : "040*"          
  }
}
```

The input to my query is url?phone=040123456

```
var query = req.query;

db.people.aggregate([{
    $match : {
        "info.phone" : query['url'] // This will only match 040*
    }
}])
```

In this case I want to match my input with the filter defined in the database.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is it you are actually asking? Is it that you want to match "040123456" against "040*"? Why not just strip your input down to be exactly that?

Comment: No can do I need the 040123456 to match my filter.

Comment: If you think about what you are asking, it is to somehow use the "regex" type expression stored in data against the whole string. That is what your question looks like anyway. The logical choice is to "strip" the query string down to match the data. Unless you actually mean something different, in which case your question could  do with editing to make that clear.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean that I should create an array like [0*, 04*, 040*, 0401*, ...] and then check if the value in db is $in that array?

Comment: I am not sure what your reasoning is for storing something that looks like a regular expression as your data. The use case here seems to be the reverse of what you are doing where the data should be the number and the query should be the expression that matches one or more items.